# Broken Entity Framework reference after update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been working on a project and needed to update the classes to a new version of a database schema.

I deleted the model class and removed the reference from the `App.config`.

After going through the steps to add a code first dbo and link it to the database again, which refreshed the classes, now all my code returns errors similar to the following:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProgram.Data.MySettings>' to System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProgram.MySettings>

An example of the code where the error occurs is shown here:

```
using MyProgram.Data;  

namespace MyProgram.Interface
{
    public class MyConfiguration
    {
        public List<MySettings> settingsList;

        public SettingsConfiguration()
        {
            using (var context = new model1())
            {
                var query = from s in context.MySettings
                            select s;

                settingsList = query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming that somehow I screwed up the model1 class or something on the import, but I can't figure out what. This issue just started occurring out of nowhere.

I expected that the import of the code first from database would just update the classes with and regenerate the model class without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

While I was using placeholder names here, the original code used a specific name that turned out to be identical to an exposed object in a dll we were using that had the same name.

I ended up having to go back and rename the imported object class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).